# How long do you have to be staying in DC before a guest concession SmarTrip is worth the extra work to acquire?

Tags: public-transport, shopping, fares, accessibility, washington-dc

I will be traveling to Washington, DC for a few days in the not-so-distant future as part of a larger trip.  I hold a valid concession (reduced) fare ID/smartcard combination issued by the transit operator in my home city, and plan to rely on WMATA to get around DC during my trip.  At what point (length of stay) should I consider getting a [visitor/courtesy reduced fare SmarTrip](https://www.wmata.com/fares/Reduced-Fare-Programs/) from the main WMATA office vs. simply acquiring a standard SmarTrip card with a 3 or 7 day unlimited pass on it?

Note that I'll be arriving in the afternoon/evening on an east coast long-distance Amtrak train, so being able to acquire a SmarTrip at or near Union Station upon arrival would be beneficial, especially if I can acquire the pass and the SmarTrip in one go.

Comment: This seems to be a shopping question (what to buy, whether it's worth it). Shopping questions are off-topic; see the [Help pages](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more. Too, the answer to "which is better" will depend on how many WMATA trips you'll take and what value you place on the convenience of acquisition. I voted to close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question both because it's a shopping question, and answers will be opinion-based.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica it's not a matter of opinion, you should buy whatever is cheaper and it is answerable how to figure out what is cheaper. you get the same metro ride, the question is how to pay the least for it.

Comment: The answer will (likely) depend on how much you expect to use public transport. When I was in DC I used it close to not at all, not worth it, but if you use it often it might work out cheaper.